# Why this regex assertion doesn't match?

Tags: regex, assertions

I'm trying to just preg content between html tags, I'm trying this simple assertion pattern and I don't understand why it doesn't match this string.

```
<a href=http://url.com title="link">this is a ling</a>

(?<=<a.*>)([ \w]*)(?=<.*\/a>)
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/MxxIxGSVJVvIzZql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lookbehinds on debuggex (PCRE, Javascript and Python) cannot be of variable width, meaning that you can use `(?<=<a>)` which has a fixed width (3 characters) but not something that can vary in length `(?<=<a.*>)` (can have 3 characters, or 4, or 5, etc).

The regex simply is not valid but debuggex tells you that there is no match.

Comment: I understand. I must find another way to do this. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @user3491049 You should be able to use something like `<a.*?>([ \w]*)<.*?\/a>` because you're getting a capture group anyway. Or if you can have the anchor `\K`, then you could perhaps use `<a.*?>\K([ \w]*)(?=<.*?\/a>)`. All the same, you should use a proper HTML parser if you're parsing HTML.

Comment: @Jerry In this context the `a` tag can/should never be nested (assuming valid HTML) so a basic RegEx should be fine.

Comment: @tenub Fair enough. I was just advising that for general HTML parsing :)

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Lookarounds".